# How to Capture Data With Dynamic Form Post Mapping Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, mapping, http-post

I have this dynamic form, where the user can add or remove rows from the form. The form takes a first name, last name and an email. I am really at a loss as to how to capture the data from the rows. If someone can point me to a resource that can help me with this I would really appreciate it! Please find below the html and JavaScript for the form, as well as the post mapping for the page.

```
<div class="container">
                                            <div class="row clearfix">
                                                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr >
                                                                <th class="text-center">
                                                                    #
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th class="text-center">
                                                                    First Name
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th class="text-center">
                                                                    Last Name
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th class="text-center">
                                                                    Email
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr id='addr0'>
                                                                <td>
                                                                1
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                <input type="text" name='firstName'  placeholder='First Name' class="form-control"/>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                <input type="text" name='lastName' placeholder='Last Name' class="form-control"/>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                <input type="text" name='email' placeholder='Email Adress' class="form-control"/>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a>
                                            <a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
                                        </div>
```

```
<script> 
         var i=1;
    $(document).ready(function(e){    
     $("#add_row").click(function()
     {
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='firstName"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='First Name' class='form-control input-md'  /></td><td><input  name='lastName"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Last Name'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='email"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Email Address'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++; 
     })});
     $(document).ready(function(e){
     $("#delete_row").click(function()
     {
         if(i>1)
         {
            $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
            i--;
         }
     })});
    </script>
```

```
//Post Mapping Contract Trace Report
    @PostMapping("/patienthome/contact-trace-report")
    public ModelAndView contractTraceReportPost(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user, @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName ) throws IOException, ParseException
    {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        
        Patient patient = patientRepo.findByEmail(authentication.getName());

        //Need to capture as many emails as there are rows
        Patient contact1 =patientRepo.findByEmail(email); 


        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/patienthome"); 
        
        modelAndView.addObject("confirmationMessage", "Patient Profile Was Updated");

        return modelAndView;   
    }
```

Thank you all in advance I really appreciate it!!!!

Comment: Instead of trying to map them as @RequestParams, pull them out of the request object -- each row has different names for the input elements.

Comment: @tgdavies Oh good idea!, but I still don't know how to capture the rows dynamically, as in I don't know how many rows there will be when the user posts the data.

Comment: Look for each name in turn (`firtsname1`, `firstname2`, ... ) until one is missing.